# virtual method functions with selection sort algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, polymorphism, virtual-functions

trying to do two things at once here by going over the select sort algorithm but more importantly learning polymorphism/virtual method functions/overriding in c++. I've done it in C# but never in c++.

I need to sort this array using the SortChild method sort, which it overrides (i think?) the Base class method of sort. But for some reason I cant get the SortChild sort method to execute.

and to be totally honest I'm not sure if I wrote the select sort algorithm correctly. Feel free to give me any hints on that as well. Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
class AbstractSort
{
public:
    //virtual void compare(int arr[], int count);
    virtual void sort(int arr[], int size)
    {
    };
};

class SortChild : public AbstractSort
{
public:
    void sort(int arr[], int size)
    {
        int temp, min;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] < arr[min])
                {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            if (min != i)
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[min];
                arr[min] = temp;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            cout << arr[x] << " ";
        }
    }
};
 int main()          
{
     int myArray[3] = {5, 1, 9};
     SortChild sr;
     AbstractSort * abs = &sr;
     sr.sort(myArray, 3);


    // This prevents the Console Window from closing during debug mode
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    cout << "\nPress only the 'Enter' key to exit program: ";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `AbstractSort` is not abstract! You would normally declare the sort function as `virtual void sort(int arr[], int size) = 0;`. However, note that `int arr[]` doesn't pass an array but a pointer! It is equivalent to passing a pointer `int* arr`, which is also preferred because it's less likely to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your virtual method seem to be fine. There was a bug in in sorting code. See the fixed code with some extra 'cout' below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class AbstractSort
{
public:
    //virtual void compare(int arr[], int count);
    virtual void sort(int arr[], int size)
    {
        cout << "super" << endl;
    };
};

class SortChild : public AbstractSort
{
public:
    void sort(int arr[], int size)
    {
        cout << "child" << endl;
        int temp, min;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] < arr[min])
                {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            if (min != i)
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[min];
                arr[min] = temp;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            cout << arr[x] << " ";
        }
    }
};
 int main()
{
     int myArray[3] = {5, 1, 9};
     SortChild sr;
     //AbstractSort * abs = &sr;
     sr.sort(myArray, 3);


    // This prevents the Console Window from closing during debug mode
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    cout << "\nPress only the 'Enter' key to exit program: ";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `SortChild` publicly inherits from `AbstractSort` : the `sort()` method is overridden and correctly called in your example.

As for the sort algorithm, you have a small typo :

```
if (arr[i] < arr[min])
       ^
   // This should be j (the index of the inner loop)
```

Live example of your working code [here](http://ideone.com/OgImHj).

**Output:**

> calling derived method
>
> 1 2 4 5 6 8 9

Answer (score 1):

```
if (arr[j] < arr[min])
{
    min = j;
}
```

one small mistake takes you a long way